# dx.jar "Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class"

Tags: android, dx

I am trying to use the `dx.Jar` tool of andorid to compile the `wechat-SDKandroid-with-mta-5.1.6.Jar` into dex file and put it into my project.

But I encountered the following warning:

```
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.tencent.mm.opensdk.diffdev.a.c) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

I've tried multiple versions of the dx.jar tool (1.16,1.7), and also used `-- optimize`, `no-strict`, `keep-classes` commands

```
java -jar dx.jar --dex --output=\JavaTempPath\classes.dex \wechat-sdk-android-with-mta-5.1.6.jar
```

or

```
java -jar dx.jar --dex --no-optimize --no-strict --keep-classes --output=\JavaTempPath\classes.dex \wechat-sdk-android-with-mta-5.1.6.jar
```

Please note that I'm not using the android studio tool for packaging, I'm just using the dx.jar tool directly, so I can't add an instruction like `-keepattributes EnclosingMethod` to the proguard file to sort it out, what I'm asking is is there any similar option in the dx.jar

Comment: It's just a warning, feel free to ignore it :)

Comment: Really? He said the reflection on this class is going to be a problem, is there an option for me to ignore this warning

Comment: Only one very specific aspect of reflection is affected. If your app's code does not use or rely on Class.getEnclosingClass and Class.getEnclosingMethod, then you can ignore the warning. Unless you're doing something very ususual, your app almost certainly doesn't use or rely on these methods.

Comment: Thanks, because I'm using the SDK, I don't know if it's available anywhere in the SDK

Comment: I ignored the warning and it worked:)